# Updating unindexed values with postgresql question

Tags: postgresql

The inexact wording of an interview question has been as follows.

> A PostgreSQL database contains a table called “apps”, having
>   millions of rows, numerous indexes, and is heavily used. There are at
>   least two columns in this table:
>
> ```
> "id": an integer serving as the primary key
> "type": a string containing unindexed values such as "SlackApp", "GithubApp", etc.
> ```
>
> You need to update this table so all occurrences of a particular
>   string in the “type” column are replaced with another string. This
>   process should take place in a migration that will be executed
>   from one of the fleet hosts while the other hosts in the fleet are
>   still running, therefore this change should happen without requiring
>   downtime.
>
> How would you go about solving this problem? What is the estimated
>   time spent in the migration process? What are the tradeoffs of your
>   solution compared to other solutions?

My answer to the above question would be to issue a transactional SQL statement to keep atomicity of operations and that would be linearly dependent on number of rows. Is there much more detail that I could add to the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL doesn't table-lock on update, it row-locks.

> You need to update this table so all occurrences of a particular string in the “type” column are replaced with another string.

That's simple,

```
UPDATE apps
SET type = regexp_replace(type, 'SearchRegex', 'Replacement', 'g')  
WHERE type ~ 'SearchRegex';
```